# Trouble moving Inline Javascript to the very end of my html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

Is it possible to move a remote inline javascript [widget](http://help.tweetmeme.com/2009/04/06/tweetmeme-button/) to the very end of my html, and then, once the DOM is ready, inject the widget inside a specific element. I see inline javascript as a candidate for poor performance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend entirely on how the widget in question is designed to be used. Looking briefly at the link you gave to TweetMeme, no, it doesn't *immediately* look like you can do that. But check the docs, they may well have a means of allowing you to do it. If they don't say they do, though, they're probably relying on writing to the document as it's being prepared, in which case you're out of luck.

**Edit**: They're using `document.write`, it won't work after-the-fact; see [the source](http://tweetmeme.com/i/scripts/button.js).